# How sum a field in a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to group all fields with the same event name, and sum the participants of this fields.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "54b6ae8aec17b5e905a5813a"
    },
    "person": {
        "name": "Something",
        "phone": "(011) 9468-1319",
        "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
        "obs": ""
    },
    "event": {
        "full": "20/11/01 Classic",
        "date": "20/11/01",
        "name": "Special",
        "participants": 10
    },
    "__v": 0
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "54b6aeaad7e410ec05dd1ca2"
    },
    "person": {
        "name": "Something",
        "phone": "(011) 9468-1319",
        "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
        "obs": ""
    },
    "event": {
        "full": "20/11/01 Classic",
        "date": "20/11/01",
        "name": "Special",
        "participants": 10
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I have just this two collections, and i am using the following code to a group by the event.full and them sum the participans (Number) field.

This is the code:

```
MyModel.aggregate(
    [
        { "$group": 
            { 
                _id: "$event.full",
                participants: { "$sum": "$participants" },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            } 
        },
        { "$skip": ( page-1 ) * 15 },
        { "$limit": 15 }
    ],
    function(err, obj) {
        res.send(obj);
    }
);
```

This is returning the following object:

```
[
 {
  _id: "20/11/01 Classic",
  participants: 0,
  count: 2
 }
]
```

Why the sum field is not working? How fix??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed the `event` use this:

```
[
        { "$group": 
            { 
                _id: "$event.full",
                participants: { "$sum": "$event.participants" },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            } 
        },
        { "$skip": ( page-1 ) * 15 },
        { "$limit": 15 }
 ]
```

Comment: happens all the time ;)